# Angular Error: Model is not of type `number`

Tags: angularjs

In my application I am getting the error:

> Angular Error: ngModel:numfmt Model is not of type `number`

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="price" type="number" name="price" placeholder="enter price" id="price" />
```

In my controller I tried putting this to stop the issue. But I didn't have any luck.

```
$scope.$watch('price', function (val, old) {
    $scope.value = parseInt(val);
});
```

How can I catch or mitigate this issue?

If you need more details don't hesitate to ask

Comment: It seems to work for me, can you post the full code or create a fiddle?

Comment: For anybody who have a similar problem : do not use quotes, when you init the price .  ng-init="price='7890'" will try to initiate the price with a string. (it is obvious, but is easy to overlook if you use a back-end framework to generate your page, where you would have ng-init="price='{{$item->price}}'"  )

Comment: This is one of many reason why I hate AngularJS. It's a framework that creates headaches for some of the most basic tasks, such as this one. Easily the least productive framework I've ever used.

Answer (score 12):

You should use `stringToNumber` directive to resolve this error. The `number` input directive `<input type="number">` requires the model to be a `number`. To store the number as a string you should use `stringToNumber` directive which convert it into the format the `input[number]` directive expects. Check below snippet.

```
<input ng-model="price" string-to-number type="number" name="price" placeholder="enter price" id="price" />
```

And here's the directive (from [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt)):

```
.directive('stringToNumber', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
        return '' + value;
      });
      ngModel.$formatters.push(function(value) {
        return parseFloat(value, 10);
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Is this built in? Will I have to add a file or change the header function?

Comment: @BDillan, yes this is built in. You just need to pass the directive in your input field.

Comment: Just note that if value is null `''+value` will print the string null, which is not what you want

Answer (score 0):

```
<input .... />
```

I have found angular to be fussy about the input it accepts. I found out the hard way, spending some time debugging something I wrote, which I passed through the notepad++ XML formatter to lay things out beautifully, in order to verify there were no mismatched tags.

The formatter replaced

```
<script .....></script>
```

with a self closing tag

```
<script ...../>
```

and the XML style self closing tags that the formatter created in my HTML prevented angular from being able interpret my file correctly.

Certain tags like <BR>, <meta> and (I think) <input> don't need closing. I don't know if this is your problem, but I would certainly edit the file to remove your self closing input tag before investigating any further.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a stringToNumber directive to parse string to number, the perfect example of this is shown at below link : https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngModel/numfmt

Answer (score 0):

this.variable = isNaN(defaultValue.value) ? defaultValue.value : parseInt(defaultValue.value);